# Where are the formulas for frequency $\omega=\sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}$, period $T=2\pi/(\sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2)}$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

Where are the formulas for frequency $\omega=\sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}$, period $T=2\pi/(\sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2)}$ got from?

For e.g. Lotka-Volterra system and associated Jacobian and eigenvalues/-vectors?

A Jacobian for a predator-prey model is:

$J=\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha-\beta y& -\beta x\\
\delta y & \delta x - \gamma
\end{bmatrix}$

At $(\gamma/\delta, \alpha/\beta)$ this is:

$J=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -\frac{\beta \gamma}{\delta}\\
\frac{\alpha \delta}{\beta} & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

For which the eigenvalues are

$\lambda_1=i\sqrt{\alpha \gamma}, \lambda_2=-i\sqrt{\alpha \gamma}$

Then it's said that:

> As the eigenvalues are both purely imaginary and conjugate to each
> others, this fixed point is elliptic, so the solutions are periodic,
> oscillating on a small ellipse around the fixed point,

therefore the frequency and period are the above.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations#Second_fixed_point_(oscillations)

Comment: Please make a complete citation, it is clear from context that the eigenvalues are $λ_{1,2}=\pm iω$, so that real solutions will have frequency $ω$. How it is written there in the wiki article is rather unfortunate, as these steps do not generalize.

Comment: @LutzLehmann What's a complete citation?

Comment: Add at least the matrix where the eigenvalues come from, just enough to understand your question without loading the wiki article.

Answer (score 1):

A matrix $$\pmatrix{0&-u\\v&0},~~~u,v>0,$$ has eigenvalues $λ_{1,2}=±iω$ where $ω=\sqrt{uv}$. As a conjugate pair on the imaginary axis or as consequence of the Viete formulas for the characteristic equation, you get also back $λ_1λ_2=ω^2=uv$, but that should only be a secondary insight.

The linearized system
$$
\dot x = -uy\\
\dot y = vx
$$
can be transformed into the scalar second order equation $\ddot x=-uvx=-ω^2x$ which is a harmonic oscillator with frequency $ω$ and thus period $2\pi/ω$.

Comment: But why is $\lambda_1 \lambda_2$ the frequency? Rather than $\omega$?

Comment: I do not know. This is an unnecessary obfuscation in the wiki article. It has no resonance with the other parts of the article, it is the whim of some editor.